# how to search recursively in prolog facts

Tags: search, prolog, counter

I have the following facts

```
%exam(Student,Subject)

exam(student1,subject1).
exam(student2,subject1).
exam(student3,subject1).

exam(student1,subject2).
exam(student3,subject2).

exam(student1,subject3).
```

I want to find the subjects of a student and put them in a list

```
Subjects(Student,[H|T]):-
                        exam(Student,Subject),
                        \\+Subject=H,
                        H = Subject,
                        Subjects(Student,T).
```

I can't figure out what the base case should be !

Comment: study [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.30%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

`\+ Subject = H` means, "*can't prove that*" `Subject` can be unified with `H`.

But since `H` starts out uninstantiated, it can always be unified with `Subject`, so that goal will always fail.

Also, to see whether `Subject` was previously found, you'd have to check its *membership* in a *list* of previously found values. That means, carrying around an additional argument from call to call, which would start as `[]`, adding newly found subject into it, and making the next call with the updated list.

As long as you can find a new fact, you add it to this accumulating list, and continue; but if you couldn't find a new fact, you should stop. That will be your base case. It'll be easier to code with auxiliary predicates each performing its separate task (like `can_find_new_subject( Student, ListSeenSoFar, Subject)` etc.).

```
subjects(Student, L):- search_subjects(Student, [], L).

search_subjects(Student, Seen, L):-
  find_new_subject(Student, Seen, Subj)
  search_subjects(Student, [Subj|Seen], L).

search_subjects(Student, Seen, L):-
  \+ find_new_subject(Student, Seen, Subj),
  ... .

find_new_subject( ......
  ....
```

The drawback to this setup is that it will be quadratic. You can't make it linear without the extra-logical facilities like `assert`, or using a built-in `findall` and the like.